# Guide me about buying a simple RAM upgrade, please

Tags: memory

Thank you for your assistance. 
My query is about **choosing between RAM upgrade models**.
I have learned from this site that *specifications must match*. So how do I choose between models with same specifications?

I have the following Kingston 4 gb ram -

```
"sodimm ddr3 synchronous 1600 mhz (0.6 ns)".
```

Now how do I select between the following options?

[This RAM model](https://www.amazon.in/Kingston-1600MHz-PC3-12800-Notebook-KVR16S11S8/dp/B008CP5R8K/ref=dp_ob_title_ce)

[or This RAM model](https://www.amazon.in/Kingston-1600MHz-DDR3L-Laptop-KVR16LS11/dp/B00CQ35GYE/ref=pd_sbs_147_1/261-6769571-7966342?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B00CQ35GYE&pd_rd_r=9642be07-00c0-4ee4-b262-743d4f230dbc&pd_rd_w=2Xpaz&pd_rd_wg=rJGjB&pf_rd_p=b5c4df7b-dc8c-47a6-947a-01271326b67b&pf_rd_r=QJKC7YZEFWF9S53B9SC4&psc=1&refRID=QJKC7YZEFWF9S53B9SC4)

There must be so many other variations. How do I choose for the upgrade?

Cheers to all reading.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you look closely, the top one is DDR3 and the bottom one is DDR3L. If your original RAM is DDR3L, then I would bet that the motherboard can only output enough voltage for DDR3L. If the motherboard can support either, then go for the cheaper one.

Comment: Thank you. I now know to buy only DDR3. Kingston authorised dealers have given me the following model as an option : KVR16N11/18 8GB PC3-12800 CL11 240-PIN DIMM     

I wonder if SODIMM and DIMM can go together. Also, my current RAM shows DIMM2, which I understand is dual channel. The new one is only DIMM. Can you assist me from hereon?

Comment: @katya sehgal SODIMM is smaller in size than DIMM.

Comment: I understand. COuld you quickly guide me about this... is my board 1.5 V or 1.35 V? In effect, do I need a DDR3L RAM or a DDR3 RAM? I am unable to figure out. Different people tell me different answers on the web. Would these details help?

ACER E5 572G Laptop
RAM Serial Number: 160CE951
RAM Part Number: ACR16D3LS1KNG/4G

Accordingly what RAM should I purchase? (DDR3L or DDR3)?

Comment: @katyl sehgal a DDR3 motherboard can use DDR3L, but a DDR3L motherboard may cause crashes when used with DDR3 because of the higher voltage required. Obviously the exact same model as what you are using is the best, but if you can't find it, I'd better be safe than sorry. DDR3L might be a bit slower.

Comment: Is it possible to find out whether my model is DDR3 or DDR3L, from the Part Number and the Serial Number? I can then try to purchase the same model.

Comment: https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Acer/aspire-e5-572g